# iPhone SE bought on eBay no longer working

Tags: iphone, warranty, applecare

I bought an unlocked iPhone SE on [eBay Germany](https://www.ebay.de) six months ago with no Apple guarantee but a 2 year **Apple Agent guarantee**. Here's what the offer said:

```
No Apple Garantie.
2 Jahr garantie vom Apple-Agent.
```

The iPhone is falling apart (the screen is popping out of the frame).  I have contacted Apple and did a warranty check and the iPhone is not under warranty.

I have the receipt and wonder why the warranty is not valid?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is primarily a legal question.

Comment: I’m gonna answer this in terms of what Apple controls so that anyone can then seek a legal remedy that would be appropriate for their specific jurisdiction. I agree, if this is really about what the law is it should be closed as off-topic. But if it’s just about understanding why Apple might deny warranty, I think that’s worth posting here.

Comment: USA ebay warranty is 30 days.  Paypal USA warranty is 180 day.  Your bank card may have a warranty. German / EU warrant laws.

Comment: This may be a third party warranty i.e. you were given a warranty by some other company than apple.  Read the original ebay posting and see if it has any contact information.  See if there is a some company listed and go to that web site.   It's quite common in USA ebay to have third party warranties on used electronics.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) If you have updated to iOS 12.2, you can go to Settings → General → About and look for Limited Warranty field just after Serial Number. If it's present, you have a valid limited warranty from Apple with the expiration date mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

This should be easy to clear up.

Apple serializes products and the warranty starts when the device is first sold. Since you are in possession of a device, register the device to your Apple ID with Apple and then ask Apple when was the original sold date.

If the listing says an apple agent warrantee is in place, I would take the device to any Apple agent you choose and get in writing that they’ve denied you warranty service.

Now you have a paper trail to take to eBay if the listing was falsified. If the listing wasn’t falsified then you bought something without the knowledge the seller had. Unfortunately this is a “feature” of many “markets” when the seller has more information than the buyer.

Since eBay is the market here, hopefully the market will compensate you if in fact the seller took illegal advantage of the marketplace rules. Or they will educate you in how their market operates and then you decide if you want to pay for out of warranty repairs.

If the seller observed the rules, there is a saying for this - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caveat_emptor